# Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0 without the user signing in

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-photos, google-photos-api

A client has requested implementation of the new [Google Photos API](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview) as a feed of their photos on the website.

The issue arises whereas the library only supports OAuth 2.0 to authorise the library requests. Meaning that each visitor needs to authenticate themselves prior to seeing the photos.

> Authorization
>   Like other Google REST APIs, the Library API uses OAuth 2.0 to handle authentication and authorization. Your app can request access to the user's Google Photos library via the various authorization scopes provided by the API.
>
> Note that the Library API does not support service accounts; to use
>   this API, users must be signed in to a valid Google Account.

Does anyone know a way that I can authenticate the library for all web traffic? I want to use Google Photos as a CMS for images and have a constant feed on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the Google Photo APIs requires OAuth 2.0 User Credentials, you will not be able to use this API as a CMS for you website.

Each API request requires an OAuth Token and this token can only be obtained by a person authenticating with Google Accounts. The OAuth Flow requires the user to authenticate and grant permission to their personal Google Account.

In addition this API requires that you create OAuth Client Secrets which is used to track your app.

Comment: Thank you John. I eventually came to that conclusion and whilst disappointed I did get to read much OAuth documentation.